# fabric ca client unable to create user for restapi

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have noticed that when I run fabric ca it start registering affiliation of the organization. But it is converting to lower case of the organization affiliations.

In **Fabric-ca-server-config.yaml** file below is the affiliations with the name **airlineOrg**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfVL4.png)

In the debug logs of fabric ca before starting the restApi server, I see the affiliation name is converting to a lower alphabet as seen below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nUWK.png)

T**he question is, why fabric ca is changing the name of configured affiliation to lower case?** because of this, I am unable to create a user.

So, what I did in the rest API server code on **getAffiliation** method I have changed organization name ex: **airlineorg** to the lower case of the organization just to test and after that, and it successfully created in the wallet.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify affiliations in the *fabric-ca-server-config.yaml* file, any non-leaf entry in the config file will be converted to lowercase.  This is actually due to a poor design which directly leverages a config library to parse/load the config file.  So if your config looks like:

```
affiliations:
  airlineOrg:
  someOtherOrg:
```

then the stored affiliations will be `airlineorg` and `someotherorg` and that is what you'll need to specify in your API calls or on the command-line.

If you config looks something like:

```
affiliations:
  airlineOrg:
    - Pilots
    - Mechanics
  someOtherOrg:
```

then only the non-leaf nodes are converted to lowercase and you access Pilots and Mechanics as `airlineorg.Pilots` and `airlineorg.Mechanics`.